# For a react native app, is there a way to view console.log output in production?

Tags: react-native, logging

For a react native app, is there a way to see console.log output in production? As far as I know this is impossible.

I know that I can write important messages to a file or to a remote database. I am looking for a simpler solution... Have you implemented such functionality using a github package that you recommend?

I am looking for a solution for android.

Comment: Logentries  is library that allows to log to remote logging service 
 link :- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-logentries

Comment: Thanks. Not to popular, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Get fancy by writing and using your own Component `<ConsoleLog>`

```
const ConsoleLog = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(children)
};
```

Then use it:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>List of todos</h1>
      <ConsoleLog>{ this.props.todos }</ConsoleLog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

if you want to log to file, use [react-native-file-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-log) package